# JDBC Statement vs. Prepared Statement SQL Injection

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

as far as I understand a "normal" JDBC Statement which is created via

```
conn.createStatement()
```

is prone to SQL-Injection. A prepared statement protects from such attacks. So why/when should I use a normal statement and when a prepared statement.

Or the other way around: If Statement is attackable why not always use prepated statements?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Is a good practice to use always prepared statements I think.